# joomla error page never gets called

Tags: joomla, http-status-code-404, joomla3.0

I have a joomla 3.1.5 installation that never calls an error page. If I open the browser to http://dev.test/DOESNOTEXIST, it shows the home page. I have read that $this->error->getCode() should return a 404 if the current page does not exist, but $this->error does not exist.

I have tried printing out $this, comparing the output of the home page to the output from a page with an invalid address, and have seen no difference, other then one being /home and the other being /DOESNOTEXIST. I have tried disabling plugins, but that doesn't seem to do it. I have tried going to my original .htaccess, but that didn't help either.

I'm running out of ideas. Has anyone else run into this issue?

Comment: have you edited any core Joomla file or the htaccess file?

Comment: I have edited the .htaccess file, but when I copy the original back, it doesn't resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have resolved the issue. I had disabled the "redirects" plugin and replaced it with a custom plugin that performed similar functions. I didn't realize at the time that the redirect plugin provides error handling through the JError::setErrorHandling method. Once I created an error handler function and linked it up, that solved the problem.